# Circle following the mouse position until clicked

Tags: java, graphics2d, mouselistener

I want to make a project that includes drawing a circle on a Java GUI. When the circle or an area around the circle is clicked, the circle should "stick" to the cursor and follow it until a mouse click happens again. Then the circle should stay where you clicked.

I made everything up to the point where the program detects that you clicked onto the circle. Circle here is a graphic made by `g2` with the `g2.fillOval` method.

There are two classes:

`MainClass.java`

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ExampleGUI g = new ExampleGUI();

    }
}
```

`ExampleGUI.java`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class ExampleGUI extends JFrame {

    Graphics2D g2;

    Point point = new Point(150,150);

    ExampleGUI() {
        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Point clicked = new Point(e.getLocationOnScreen().x - getX(),e.getLocationOnScreen().y - getY());

                if(clickedaroundpoint(clicked)){
                    System.out.println("Clicked on Point");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        };

        this.addMouseListener(ml);
        setTitle("FlamingoBall");
        setSize(300,300);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private boolean clickedaroundpoint(Point clicked) {
        if(Point.distance(point.x+2,point.y+2,clicked.x,clicked.y)<=5){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillOval(point.x,point.y,7,7);
    }
}
```

Please let me know what the best way is to keep going.

Comment: Don't override `paint` and call super.paintComponent, override `paintComponent`, and call super.paintComponent.

Comment: @matt One should not inherit from `JFrame` in the first place. (It does not have a `paintComponent` method, by the way...)

Comment: @Marco13 good eye, I thought it was a Component like a JPanel. I didn't even realize it was a JFrame.

Comment: @matt Why can't I do that? This is the template we used in school.

Comment: If you override paint on a JFrame it is much less portable. What if you want to add something else to the layout, or if you want to use the component in a different layout/JFrame/Dialog. You'll find it more practical to extend a JPanel, and then override paintComponent as per the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `MouseMotionListener` and implement `mouseMoved()`, or `mouseDragged()` if you like.

There are multiple ways how you could do that. It depends on whether you want click-move or drag. The difference is:

- click-move: press, release, move, press, release
- drag: press, move, release

## Click-move

In that case you need to implement

- The `mouseClicked()` handler of the `MouseListener` observer to toggle a `boolean` and remember the start position of the movement.
- The `mouseMoved()` of the `MouseMotionListener` observer to perform the actual movement.

Like this:

```
class Mover implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private boolean moving;
    private Point movementOrigin;
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (moving = !moving)
            movementOrigin = e.getPoint();
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!moving) return;
        Point pos = e.getPoint();
        Point delta = new Point(pos.getX() - movementOrigin.getX(), pos.getY() - movementOrigin.getY());
        // TODO Relocate the circle with that delta
        repaint();
    }
}
```

## Drag

In that case, you need to implement
* The `mousePressed()` handler of the `MouseListener` observer for the start position of the drag.
* The `mouseDragged()` handler of the `MouseMotionListener` observer for following the drag movement.

The only difference to the code before is that you do not need that boolean toggle.

## Note about original answer

In my original answer I suggested to dynamically add/remove the `MouseMotionListener` in the corresponding event of the `MouseListener`. I no longer think that this is a good idea, because there is no "cheap" way to detect whether an observer was already registered, and thus a boolean would be needed anyway.

## Note about the code

I don't think that having a field of type `Graphics2D` initialized from a `paint()` method is a good idea. The validity of an on-screen `Graphics` object is probably bound to the `repaint()` call tree. Calling its methods outside of the `repaint()` call tree is probably going to result in undefined behavior. The lifetime of the `Graphics` object is the `repaint()` call tree, not the `ExampleGUI` object, and the code should reflect that by not caching it in a field.

Extending UI classes (your `extends JFrame`) for usage is an anti-pattern and violates the Liskov Substitution Principle. Inheritance is (still) overused. Consider using delegation instead of inheritance.

Comment: Adding and removing a `MouseMotionListener` should not be necessary. After all, the movement should be tracked after a **click**, and not after a `mousePressed`. So there will likely be some state like a `boolean isMovingPoint` that is set to `true` with the first click, and to `false` with the second click.

Comment: @Marco13 This is just an example that was made for this question specificaly. In the original I do have booleans that do excactly this.